# Tkinter Scrollbar fails with .place() method

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am attempting to add a scrollbar to my sample GUI. The GUI is very simple, it has two frames. The left frame contains Button1. The right most frame will add a label "Button 1 was pressed" every time Button 1 is pressed. The purpose of the scrollbar is to rectify the fact that once you press Button 1 enough times the length of the labels exceeds the length of the window. I have managed to produce code that works correctly. This code uses .pack() method to place frames, labels, etc... However, I would like to use the .place() method instead, however when replacing .pack() with .place(), execution of the code provides an empty GUI.

Here is the code that uses the .pack() method. It works as intended.

```
import tkinter as tk

def button1_pressed():
    text = "Button 1 was pressed"
    label_text.append(text)
    update_label()

def update_label():
    label.config(text="\n".join(label_text))
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Scrollable Label")

# Create two frames
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# Create a button in the left frame
button1 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Button 1", command=button1_pressed)
button1.pack()

# Create a scrollable label in the right frame
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame2, width=200, height=150)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame2, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

label_text = []
label = tk.Label(canvas, text="")
label.pack()

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=label, anchor='nw')
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the code that uses the .place() method. It results in an empty GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk

def button1_pressed():
    text = "Button 1 was pressed"
    label_text.append(text)
    update_label()

def update_label():
    label.config(text="\n".join(label_text))
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Scrollable Label")

# Create two frames
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.place(x=0, y=0, anchor='nw')

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.place(x=300, y=0, anchor='nw')

# Create a button in the left frame
button1 = tk.Button(frame1, text="Button 1", command=button1_pressed)
button1.place(x=100, y=75, anchor='center')

# Create a scrollable label in the right frame
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame2, width=200, height=150)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame2, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

label_text = []
label = tk.Label(canvas, text="")
label.pack()

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=label, anchor='nw')
canvas.place(x=0, y=0, anchor='nw')
scrollbar.place(x=200, y=0, anchor='ne', relheight=1)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

I do not know where the problem lies. Tkinter seems fine with creating a frame, creating a canvas within the frame, and then using the .place() method to place a label as shown in the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Frame with Canvas and Label")

# Create a frame
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=200, height=150, bg="lightgray")
frame.place(x=50, y=50)

# Create a canvas within the frame
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=200, height=150, bg="white")
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

# Create a label on the canvas
label = tk.Label(canvas, text="Label")
label.place(x=100, y=75, anchor='center')

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `grid` and `pack`, `place` will not cause the containing widget to resize to fit its children. When you use `place` the size of all widgets is your responsibility.

The reason your GUI seems empty is that you haven't given the widgets a size, and you haven't used any `place` arguments to tell the widgets how to grow or shrink in relation to their parent. Thus, `frame1` and `frame2` are only 1x1 pixels wide/tall. If you give them an explicit size, you'll see them. It also helps during development to give them unique colors so that they are easily identifiable.

The best solution is to not use `place`. It has its uses, but as a general purpose layout tool it is more difficult to use than `pack` and `grid`.